# Do not impact database with test

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

In symfony 1.x, with some code it was possible to run test without modify database. For example, one of my test test the registration of user. After executing this test, ths user is always in database.
How can we execute tests without modifying database permanently ?

Comment: Track your modifications and undo them afterwards. Or create a test database. Once you've modified the database, it has been modified - there is no "undo" button. So you have to build one your self. If you insert a row, delete it afterwards. If you modify a row, select it and store it first so you can put it back afterwards. Same goes if you delete one. Alternatively (better) have a test database that mirrors the live database, and do your testing with that.

Comment: Ouch, it was not a better way in sf 1.x ? I think a database for test is better, but i have to reinitialize her between each tests for security no ? :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is [this](http://alexandre-salome.fr/blog/Symfony2-Isolation-Of-Tests) excellent article by Alexandre who describes how to rollback database after each test.

What is also possible is using sqlite as test-database because it is in-memory and therefor much faster. [This article](http://blog.sznapka.pl/fully-isolated-tests-in-symfony2/) describes how to do this. This approach is handy if you need to handle data between tests, like creating an object and then editing it. This is not good pratice but sometimes there is no way around.

I use a split approach, having a sqlite database for speed and doing a rollback after every test as described by Alexandre. It works very well :-)

Comment: Thank you! i use the first link (Alexandre Salome blog) and it work. I have problem with doctrine (some entity retrieve with doctrine are not 'linked': "A new entity was found through the relationship  ...") but i don't no if it's linked to this script.